# How to implement another variation of clone(2) syscall in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls, glibc

I'm trying to create another version of clone(2) syscall(in kernel space) to create a clone of a user process with some additional parameters.This system call will be doing exactly the same job as clone(2) but I want to pass one additional parameters to the kernel from user_space.However when I see the glibc's [code](http://osxr.org:8080/glibc/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S)
it seems that every parameter are not passed in the same order as user's call of the clone()

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,
             int flags, void *arg, ...
             /* pid_t *ptid, void *newtls, pid_t *ctid */ );
```

rather some of them are handled by glibc's code itself.I searched the internet to learn how glib's clone() works but couldn't find any better documentation.
Can anyone please explain

1. How glibc handles the clone()?
2. And also all the parameters of syscall in kernel are not exactly the same as clone in glibc, so how is these variation handled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How glibc handles the clone()?

Via arch-specific assembly wrappers. For i386, see [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S) in the glibc sources; for x86-64, see [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86-64/clone.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S), and so on.

The normal syscall wrappers are not sufficient, because it is up to the userspace to switch stacks. The above assembly files have pretty informative comments as to what actually needs to be done in userspace in addition to the syscall.

---

> All the parameters of syscall in kernel are not exactly the same as clone in glibc, so how is these variation handled?

C library functions that map to a syscall are wrapper functions.

Consider, for example, the POSIX.1 [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) C library low-level I/O function, and the Linux `write()` syscall. The parameters are basically the same, as are the error conditions, but the error return values differ. The C library function returns `-1` with `errno` set if an error occurs, whereas the Linux syscall returns negative error codes (which basically match `errno` values).

If you look at e.g. [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h), you can see that the basic syscall wrapper for Linux on x86-64 boils down to

```
# define INLINE_SYSCALL(name, nr, args...) \
  ({                                       \
    unsigned long int resultvar = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args);        \
    if (__glibc_unlikely (INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P (resultvar, )))            \
      {                                                                       \
        __set_errno (INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERRNO (resultvar, ));                   \
        resultvar = (unsigned long int) -1;                                   \
      }                                                                       \
    (long int) resultvar; })
```

which just calls the actual syscall, then checks if the syscall return value indicated an error; and if it does, changes the result to `-1` and sets `errno` accordingly. It's just funny-looking, because it relies on GCC extensions to make it behave as a single statement.

---

Let's say you added a new syscall to Linux, say

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(splork, unsigned long, arg1, void *, arg2);
```

and, for whatever reasons, you wish to expose it to userspace as

```
int splork(void *arg2, unsigned long arg1);
```

No problem! All you need is to provide a minimal header file,

```
#ifndef _SPLORK_H
#define _SPLORK_H
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef __NR_splork
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define __NR_splork /* syscall number on x86-64 */
#else
#if defined(__i386)
#define __NR_splork /* syscall number on i386 */
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __NR_splork
#ifndef SYS_splork
#define SYS_splork __NR_splork
#endif

int splork(void *arg2, unsigned long arg1)
{
    long retval;

    retval = syscall(__NR_splork, (long)arg1, (void *)arg2);
    if (retval < 0) {
        /* Note: For backward compatibility, we might wish to use
                     *(__errno_location()) = -retval;
                 here. */
        errno = -retval;
        return -1;
    } else
        return (int)retval;
}

#else
#undef SYS_splork

int splork(void *arg2, unsigned long arg1)
{
    /* Note: For backward compatibility, we might wish to use
                 *(__errno_location()) = ENOTSUP;
             here. */
    errno = ENOTSUP;
    return -1;
}

#endif

#endif /* _SPLORK_H */
```

The `SYS_splork` and `__NR_splork` are preprocessor macros defining the syscall number for the new syscall. Since the syscall number is likely not (yet?) included in the official kernel sources and headers, the above header file explicitly declares it for each supported architecture. For architectures where it is not supported, the `splork()` function will always return `-1` with `errno == ENOTSUP`.

Note, however, that Linux syscalls are limited to 6 parameters. If your kernel function needs more, you need to pack the parameters into a structure, pass the address of that structure to the kernel, and use `copy_from_user()` to copy the values to the same structure in-kernel.

In all Linux architectures, pointers and `long` are of the same size (`int` may be smaller than pointer), so I recommend you use either `long` or fixed-size types in such structures to pass data to/from the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It possible to use the clone syscall with almost no assembler.

The problem is not the stack switching which is done by the kernel as part of the system call but likely the glibc `syscall()` wrapper.

Using these bare-bones wrappers instead:

```
long _x64_syscall0(long n) {
  long ret;
  __asm__ __volatile__("syscall" : "=a"(ret) : "a"(n) : "rcx", "r11", "memory");
  return ret;
}


long _x64_syscall5(long n, long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5) {
  long ret;
  register long r10 __asm__("r10") = a4;
  register long r8 __asm__("r8") = a5;
  __asm__ __volatile__("syscall"
                       : "=a"(ret)
                       : "a"(n), "D"(a1), "S"(a2), "d"(a3), "r"(r10), "r"(r8)
                       : "rcx", "r11", "memory");
  return ret;
}
```

A sketch of clone usage would look like:

```
    int ret = _x64_syscall5(56 /* clone */ , CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, 
                              (long long)new_stack, 0, 0, 0);
    if (ret == 0) {
      // we are the child
      ChildFunc();
      _x64_syscall0(60 /* exit */ );
    } else {
      // we are the parent
    }
```